# Change array in the TextView

Tags: android, arrays

I've got an array:

```
int[][] a = new int [50][50];
```

Then, i'm write it into TextView ( variable: table)

```
StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int ii = 0; ii <= pow(2,n); ii++){//strings of the truth table
    for(int jj = 1; jj <= pow(2,n); jj++){//rows...
        strBuild.append(a[ii][jj]);
        strBuild.append(" ");
    }
    strBuild.append("\n");
}

table.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

i've got next array (n=2 and defines dynamically)

```
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
```

But i want to get an array 2^n, 4x4 here, but if i will do

```
for(int jj = 1; jj <= pow(2,n); jj++){
```

instead of

```
for(int jj = 0; jj <= pow(2,n); jj++){
```

i will lose the third element in the first row.

How i can move this value down to obtain next array?

```
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
```

Comment: What if you change "<=" (less or equal) condition to "<" (less) in both loops? Then `ii` and `jj` will be in the range 0..3

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 4x4, what is giving the 5th row is:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii <= pow(2,n); ii++)
```

so you can change this to:

```
for(int ii = 0; ii < pow(2,n); ii++)
```

and that will give you 4 rows. Let me know if you have any more questions in the comments.